# Python Implementation for Dijkstra's Algorithm doesn't work with all graph types

Tags: python, dijkstra, path-finding, greedy

Below is the code I wrote for the implementation and it works perfectly with the graph named 'graph' initialised before the function. But it keeps running into errors with 'graph2'.

```
'''
The graphs below will be used to test the directed and
undirected capabilities of my algorithm.

'''
graph = {"A": {"B": 2, "C" : 4},
         "B" : {"C" : 5, "D" : 6},
         "C" : {"D" : 2}
        }

graph2 = {"A" : {"B" : 4, "C" : 2, "D" : 8},
          "B" : {"A" : 4, "C" : 1, "D" : 3},
          "C" : {"A" : 2, "B" : 1, "D" : 4},
          "D" : {"A" : 8, "B" : 3, "C" : 4}
         }


infinity = float("inf")

start = "A"
end = "D"

def DijkstrasAlgorithm(grid, sourceNode, endNode):
    # "allnodes" is used to contain all nodes present in the grid inputted into the function.
    # "visitedNodes" is used to store nodes that have been visited.
    # "distances" stores edges (connections between 2 nodes) and their weights (the magnitude of their distance).
    # "parents" is a dictionary used to form the basis with which the shortest path can be outputted, by interlinking the 
    # the parents of each class from the start to the end.
    currentNode, allNodes, visitedNodes = sourceNode, set(), set()
    distances, parents, paths = [], dict(), []

    # This for loop adds all individual nodes to the set, which becomes a list, called 'allNodes'
    for i in grid:
        allNodes.add(i)
        for j in grid[i]:
            allNodes.add(j)
    allNodes = sorted(list(allNodes))

    #This for loop sets all distances between all nodes equal to infinity
    for i in grid:
        for j in grid[i]:
            distances.append([i, j, infinity])                  

    #This for loop sets the initial parent node of all nodes equal to None

    for node in allNodes:
        parents[node] = None

    # This for loops sets the distances for all nodes that can be set   
    for i in grid:
        for j in grid[i]:
            try:
                distances.append([i, j, grid[i][j]])
                distances.remove([i, j, infinity])
            except KeyError:
                continue
            except:
                print("Error occurred during edge weight update.")

    # This while  loop is the actual part of the code that accounts for Dijkstras algorithm
    # it continues to iterate choosing the node of minimum distance until the length of the 'allNodes' set is equal to zero

    while len(allNodes) > 0:
        # This if-statement ends the loop once the destination has been reached
        if currentNode == endNode:
            break

        # These 2 statements remove the current node from the 'allNodes' set and add them to
        # the visited nodes set
        allNodes.remove(currentNode)
        visitedNodes.add(currentNode)
        comparisonRange = []
        # This for loop chooses the closes nodes to the comparison node to compare
        # and select the node of minimum distance
        for edge in distances:
            if (edge[0] == currentNode) and (edge[1] not in visitedNodes):
                comparisonRange.append(edge)
        comparisonRange = sorted(comparisonRange, key = lambda x: x[2])
        parents[comparisonRange[0][1]] = currentNode
        currentNode = comparisonRange[0][1]
        # The above code is the 'greedy' part of the algorithm selecting the node of minimum distance
        # each time

    possiblePath = []

    # The for loop below appends the nodes in order of visitation
    # Its starts with the node whose parent is still None, which can only be the start node
    # and all nodes that branch from it and so on so forth are appended to the possiblePath list.
    # This ensures possible path holds the nodes in order of visitation.
    for node in parents.keys():
        if parents[node] == None:
            possiblePath.append(node)

        if parents[node] in possiblePath:
            possiblePath.append(node)

    # This code adds one possible path to the group of possible paths named 'paths'

    paths.append(possiblePath)

    # This for loop creates other possible paths spanning from the first one
    # simply by deleting a previous choice
    for i in range(len(paths[0]) - 1):
        alternatePath = [element for element in paths[i]]
        alternatePath.pop(1)
        if len(alternatePath) == 2:
            break
        paths.append(alternatePath)

    # This list holds zero for the initial length of each possible path
    pathLengths =[[0] for item in paths]

    # This for loop is used to calculate the lengths of possible paths from
    # items contained within each possible path. This is done by passing those 
    # items into the 'graph' dictionary and calculating the length between them
    for path in paths:
        length = 0
        for index in path:  
            try:
                for secondKey in grid[index]:
                    if secondKey == path[path.index(index)+1]:
                        try:
                            length += grid[index][secondKey]
                        except KeyError:
                            continue          
                    pathLengths[paths.index(path)] = length
            except KeyError:
                continue

    # The minimum path variable below chooses the minimum length in pathLengths
    # and uses that index to find the path that it corresponds to in the list
    # paths 
    minimumPath = paths[pathLengths.index(min(pathLengths))]

    return minimumPath

DijkstrasAlgorithm(graph, start, end)
```

I also contemplated using classes but I don't know how to implement them.

Please tell me what you think, give me suggestions on how to improve the code and my programming skills in general, and could you also notify me of any methods I could use to ensure that my implementation can work on any graph inputted into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the *adjacency matrix* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) in graph algorithms because it is faster, like in https://gist.github.com/shintoishere/f0fa40fe1134b20e7729

Comment: Yes, faster and simpler.

Comment: Thank you, based on what I actually wrote would say that my code is 'clean'/'pythonic'. If not how could I improve?